# Compilation error from code with structure

Tags: c, struct

I try to complile this:

```
#define VAR_COUNT 5
typedef struct {
  uint32_t value;
  char name[10];
} variable;

variable cfg[VAR_COUNT];

cfg[0].value = 0;
cfg[0].name = "test";
```

But get error:

```
src/variables.c:26:7: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
cfg[0].value = 0;
src/variables.c:27:7: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
cfg[0].name = "test";
```

That's really unexpected error for me. I think that my structure array is wrong, but with this code:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t value;
  char name[10];
} variable;

variable cfg;

cfg.value = 0;
cfg.name = "test";
```

I get the same error.

Upd: I add function

```
void set (variable data, uint32_t value) {
  data.value = value;
}
```

And in its scope I can work with structure element without an error.

Thanks to all, problem has solved, **you should always fully awake before you make some C code.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an array, but you can copy to it:

```
strcpy(cfg[0].name, "test");
```

Comment: okay, but why w/out array I get the same error?

upd: I try to add your code, but get another error: 
    src/variables.c:26:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'cfg'
     strcpy(cfg[0].name, "test");
    src/variables.c:26:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
    strcpy(cfg[0].name, "test");

Comment: @Anper It's the array `name` inside the structure that's the problem, not the `cfg` array.

Comment: More to the point, `cfg.value = 0;` and friends need to be inside a function, anyway.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, you are right, I must work with structure only in function!

Comment: @Anper: *All* statements have to go in functions in C, not just those dealing with `struct`s.

Comment: Yes, I look at all my other C code, and there are no out-of-function assign, only assign initial value when declare variables… Maybe 7 o'clock is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Statements must be inside a function. For example:

```
int main()
{
    cfg[0].value = 0;
    strcpy(cfg[0].name, "test");
}
```

Statements get executed when program flow reaches that point. There is no program flow outside of a function; program flow starts at the start of `main()`.

You can use initializers in your declaration , outside of a function (which are not part of program flow, they get set as a bloc before flow starts):

```
variable cfg[VAR_COUNT] = {
    { 0, "test" },
    { 5, "bar" },
    { 7, "tennis" }
};
```

This initializes everything in the same order; you can also use *designated initializers* here.